# Swift 3 - Only able to extract very little amount of EXIF Data

Tags: swift3

I'm new in Swift and I am trying to develop an EXIF Viewer for iOS using Swift 3. Currently, I am only able to extract a very little amount of data (ColorModel, Depth, PixelHeight, PixelWidth, ProfileName, etc) from the image but the same image on my Macbook and iPhone contains a lot more EXIF.

**Storyboard 1:
User choose an image from Camera Roll and click the "Use" button.**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var viewActiveImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var useCamera: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var useCameraRoll: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var useActiveImage: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var clearActiveImage: UIBarButtonItem!

    var isNewImage: Bool?

    @IBAction func useCamera(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            isNewImage = true
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Lookup Failed", message: "No camera is found on device", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func useCameraRoll(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            isNewImage = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func useActiveImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if viewActiveImage.image == nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Selection Failed", message: "No image selected", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ExifDataViewer", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "exif") as UIViewController
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func clearActiveImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        viewActiveImage.image = nil
    }

    func convertUIImageToNSData(selectionAsUIImage: UIImage) -> NSData {
        return (UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectionAsUIImage) as NSData?)!
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if mediaType.isEqual(to: kUTTypeImage as String) {
            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            ExifDataViewController.currentActiveImage = convertUIImageToNSData(selectionAsUIImage: image)
            viewActiveImage.image = image
            if (isNewImage == true) {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(ViewController.image(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
            }
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Selection Failed", message: "Media selected is not an image", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo:UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if error != nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save Failed", message: "Failed to save image", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Storyboard 2: Process the image and display the EXIF data in Table View**

```
class ExifDataViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for item in arrayEXIFDictionaryKeys {
            extractExifPropertyFromNSData(selectionAsNSData: ExifDataViewController.currentActiveImage, nameOfExifProperty: item as! String)
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}

    // OUTLETS


    // VARIABLES DECLARATION
    static var currentActiveImage = NSData()

    // ARRAY PROPERTIES
    let arrayEXIFDictionaryKeys = [
        kCGImagePropertyExifExposureTime,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFNumber,
        kCGImagePropertyExifExposureProgram,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSpectralSensitivity,
        kCGImagePropertyExifISOSpeedRatings,
        kCGImagePropertyExifOECF,
        kCGImagePropertyExifVersion,
        kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal,
        kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized,
        kCGImagePropertyExifComponentsConfiguration,
        kCGImagePropertyExifCompressedBitsPerPixel,
        kCGImagePropertyExifShutterSpeedValue,
        kCGImagePropertyExifApertureValue,
        kCGImagePropertyExifBrightnessValue,
        kCGImagePropertyExifExposureBiasValue,
        kCGImagePropertyExifMaxApertureValue,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSubjectDistance,
        kCGImagePropertyExifMeteringMode,
        kCGImagePropertyExifLightSource,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFlash,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFocalLength,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSubjectArea,
        kCGImagePropertyExifMakerNote,
        kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTime,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeOriginal,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeDigitized,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFlashPixVersion,
        kCGImagePropertyExifColorSpace,
        kCGImagePropertyExifPixelXDimension,
        kCGImagePropertyExifPixelYDimension,
        kCGImagePropertyExifRelatedSoundFile,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFlashEnergy,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSpatialFrequencyResponse,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFocalPlaneXResolution,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFocalPlaneYResolution,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFocalPlaneResolutionUnit,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSubjectLocation,
        kCGImagePropertyExifExposureIndex,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSensingMethod,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFileSource,
        kCGImagePropertyExifCFAPattern,
        kCGImagePropertyExifCustomRendered,
        kCGImagePropertyExifExposureMode,
        kCGImagePropertyExifWhiteBalance,
        kCGImagePropertyExifDigitalZoomRatio,
        kCGImagePropertyExifFocalLenIn35mmFilm,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSceneCaptureType,
        kCGImagePropertyExifGainControl,
        kCGImagePropertyExifContrast,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSaturation,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSharpness,
        kCGImagePropertyExifDeviceSettingDescription,
        kCGImagePropertyExifSubjectDistRange,
        kCGImagePropertyExifImageUniqueID,
        kCGImagePropertyExifGamma,
        kCGImagePropertyExifCameraOwnerName,
        kCGImagePropertyExifBodySerialNumber,
        kCGImagePropertyExifLensSpecification,
        kCGImagePropertyExifLensMake,
        kCGImagePropertyExifLensModel,
        kCGImagePropertyExifLensSerialNumber] as [Any]

    let arrayIndividualImageProperties = [
        kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight,
        kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth,
        kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight,
        kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth,
        kCGImagePropertyDepth,
        kCGImagePropertyOrientation,
        kCGImagePropertyIsFloat,
        kCGImagePropertyIsIndexed,
        kCGImagePropertyHasAlpha,
        kCGImagePropertyColorModel,
        kCGImagePropertyProfileName] as [Any]

    // BACK TO SELECTION SCREEN
    @IBAction func returnToMain() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "main") as UIViewController
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // SHARE EXIF RESULTS
    @IBAction func shareImageResults() {

    }

    // GET EXIF PROPERTY
    func extractExifPropertyFromNSData(selectionAsNSData: NSData, nameOfExifProperty: String) {
        if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(selectionAsNSData as CFData, nil) {
            let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)
            let imageDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: imageProperties!)
            print(imageProperties)
            addExifPropertyToTable(displayString: imageDictionary.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: [nameOfExifProperty as String]))
        }
    }

    // ADD PROPERTY TO TABLE
    func addExifPropertyToTable(displayString: [String:Any]) {
        //print(displayString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import Photos 
import PhotosUI

 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        let assetURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
        let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetURL as URL], options: nil)
        guard let result = asset.firstObject else {
            return
        }

        let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
        imageManager.requestImageData(for: result , options: nil, resultHandler:{
            (data, responseString, imageOriet, info) -> Void in
            let imageData: NSData = data! as NSData
            if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData, nil) {
                let imageProperties2 = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)! as NSDictionary
                print("imageProperties2: ", imageProperties2)
            }

        })
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```